# Is it necessary to define our own action creators in Redux Toolkit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, frontend, redux-toolkit

So, I was trying to figure out the best way to use the redux toolkit in my react projects. This is my current way of writing a typical slice in redux toolkit along with redux-thunk to make API calls.

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";
import { baseUrl } from "../../../baseUrl";
const searchTrip = createSlice({
    name: "searchTrip",
    initialState: {
        isLoading: false,
        data: null,
        success: false,
    },
    reducers: {
        sendRequest: (state, action) => ({
            ...state,
            isLoading: true,
        }),
        sendSuccess: (state, action) => ({
            ...state,
            isLoading: false,
            errMess: null,
            data: action.data,
            success: true,
        }),
        sendFailed: (state, action) => ({
            ...state,
            isLoading: false,
            errMess: action.message,
            success: false,
        }),
    },
});
export const { sendFailed, sendRequest, sendSuccess } = searchTrip.actions;
```

//action creators:

```
export const requestSend = () => {
    return {
        type: sendRequest.type,
    };
};

export const receiveSend = (response) => {
    return {
        type: sendSuccess.type,
        data: response,
    };
};

export const sendError = (message) => {
    return {
        type: sendFailed.type,
        message,
    };
};
```

//redux thunk to make API call

```
 export const postSearchTrip = (data) => (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(requestSend());
        const call = {
            url: baseUrl + "trips/search",
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
            },
            data: {
                search: data,
            },
        };
        return axios(call)
            .then((response) => {
                dispatch(receiveSend(response.data));
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                dispatch(sendError(error.message));
                alert(error);
            });
    };
    export default searchTrip.reducer;
```

now, I feel like the action creator part is repeated for every slice, and is there a way to not use it. Can I directly use sendSuccess, sendRequest, etc. ??

Also, can reducers of two slices have the same name? like for general API calls I name my reducers sendRequest, sendSuccess, and sendFaliure and copy-paste this part across all slices. will this create any problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the point of `createSlice` is that **it automatically generates action creators for you - you don't (and *shouldn't*) be writing action creators yourself!**

When you wrote your own `requestSend()` function, you're just duplicating what `createSlice` already did for you. You can stop doing that completely :)

Also, note that:

- Redux Toolkit already has [a `createAsyncThunk` API](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk) that simplifies the process of making async requests and dispatching actions
- We're about to release a new ["RTK Query" API](https://deploy-preview-1016--redux-starter-kit-docs.netlify.app/tutorials/rtk-query) that will abstract the data fetching process completely - no need to write *any* thunks or reducers at all just to fetch data